# How to change the button color when it is active using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. I want to change button color when I click on button.I mean button should be in different color when it is selected. How can I do this using css?

My codes are :

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1">Button1</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery toggle class for this.

Comment: how can i do this? plz make a jsfiddle if it possible.

Comment: view this demo..... https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/cyu0u9rk/1/

Comment: This one is also right.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, please vote to me. Second answer is mine.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

CSS has different pseudo selector by which you can achieve such effect. In your case you can use

> **:active** : if you want background color only when the button is clicked and don't want to persist.
>
> **:focus**: if you want background color untill the focus is on the button.

```
button:active{
    background:olive;
}
```

and

```
button:focus{
    background:olive;
}
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vt1bzpsq/)

P.S.: Please don't give the number in `Id` attribute of html elements.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Actually i am calling javascript using the id. and it was working correctly.

Comment: Please provide the reason of downvote while doing it. It would help me to find out the issue as well as it will be good for the OP.

Comment: I didn't do this. Your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the `focus`, wasn't trivial to find out.

Comment: Just like to point out this won't work in Firefox. You'll have to play around with the -moz-focus-inner attribute but there isn't one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Just for my curiousity, whats wrong with using numbers as id? I cant think of any downsides

Answer (score 8):

`CSS` has many pseudo `selector like, :active, :hover,` `:focus` so you can use.

```css
.btn{
    background: #ccc;
} .btn:focus{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2">Button2</button>
        </div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qxhLjwz/)

Answer (score 4):

HTML--

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1">Button1</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2">Button2</button>
</div>
```

css--

```
.active{
         background:red;
    }
 button.btn:active{
     background:red;
 }
```

jQuery--

```
jQuery("#my_styles .btn").click(function(){
    jQuery("#my_styles .btn").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
```

});

view the live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/cyu0u9rk/1/)

Comment: A little late maybe, but I find your answer more appropriate than the rest. I viewed the jsfiddle. But I am having trouble as to how I should include it in my program. Is there anything I need to import? It worked fine on the fiddle, not in my program though. I placed the jquery in the `<script>`. What else do i need to do?

Comment: Check browser console message. make sure you have loaded jquery before above jquery