# Changing the Color of button on Click in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of the button on click .  I am doing it on the Bootstrap button which is blue. But my code is not working.

With my JavaScript code following, it is not changing the color.

```
<button type="button" id="btnOUs" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelOU()">Organization Units </button>
</button>

<button type="button" id="btnchiefdom" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelCD()">Chiefdom</button>
</button>

<button type="button" id="btndistrict" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelD()">District </button>
</button>

<button type="button" id="btnfaciltiy" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelF()">Facility </button>
</button>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var b1 = document.getElementById("btnOUS");
var b2 = document.getElementById("btnchiefdom");
var b2 = document.getElementById("btndistrict");
var b2 = document.getElementById("btnfacility");

b1.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "green";
     b2.style.background = "";   
}

b2.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "";
     b2.style.background = "green";   
}

b2.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "";
     b2.style.background = "green";   
}
b2.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "";
     b2.style.background = "green";   
}
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: Wrap all your code in `window.onload=function(){/*your code here*/}`

Comment: @leo.fcx check my answer please.

Comment: @imadfookifooki you get this error because you're trying to set onclick to element with wrong `id`, check my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See this functional example:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="btnOUs" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelOU()">Organization Unitss </button>
            <button type="button" id="btnchiefdom" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelCD()">Chiefdom</button>
            <button type="button" id="btndistrict" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelD()">District </button>
            <button type="button" id="btnfaciltiy" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelF()">Facility </button>
```

Comment: When you click on button,`active` class is assigned to the clicked button, but first, all buttons with the `active` class will be cleaned.

Comment: Instead of the custom class `active` you can use predefined green class `btn-success`.

Comment: That's right, but he is using the green color and the `btn-success` class  uses `#449D44`, that's my reason.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't like the other answers because they either required `jquery` or `!important`

In bootstrap, the `:active` element state for bootstrap buttons is more specified than it is for other element states (to understand what this means, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27704409/5645583)). This is why you may find yourself able to control the css of `:hover` but find that `:active` mysteriously doesn't work.

The way I got around this was by simply increasing the specificity of my css class. For example:

```
.my-button:active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I changed it to

```
.my-button:not(:disabled):not(:disabled):active {
   background-color: green;
}
```

This gives it equal specificity to the bootstrap `btn:active`. Then I made sure my custom class appears first in the ordering.

```
<a href="foobar" class="my-button btn btn-primary btn-lg">Connect with Us</a>
```

Hope this helps! Just my personal solution.

Comment: This is far better than using `!important` or using javascript to change its style.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"btnOUS"` by `"btnOUs"` (small `s`) in :

```
var b1 = document.getElementById("btnOUS");
_______________________________________^
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Basic example :**

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("btnOUs");

b1.onclick = function() {
  b1.style.background = "green";  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="btnOUs" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="levelOU()">Organization Units </button>
```

Comment: can you please give more explanation

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null  I am getting this error

Comment: You can see that it work here, in your example you have 3 variable with same name, please try to reorganize your code.

Answer (score 1):

try this. same for other buttons.just need to change the id name

```
 $("#btnfacility").click(function () {
            $(this).css({"background-color":"green !important"});
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS pseudo selector:

> **active** : if you want background color only when the button is clicked and don't want to persist.

```
btn.btn-primary:active
{
    background-color:grey !important; /* add here any color */
}
```

```css
  
    
    .btn.btn-warning:hover{
        background: yellow;
    }
    
    /** on active **/
    
   .btn.btn-warning:active{
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1">Click me please!!</button>
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712267/how-to-change-the-button-color-when-it-is-active-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can create css classes and simply change the class on click.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also, I think you should provide an example for the alternative that you suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can also take two button instead one them should be green and another should be blue and apply show and hind function of jquery.

`(#blue).click(function(){
  (#blue).hide();
  (#green).show();
})`

initally #green button should be hide.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#btnid").click(function (){ $(this).css("color","green"); }`
**Please try this**
css() function use to style the object. I add on click event of button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap button class to change color of button.

```js
$('.btn-success').on("click",function(){
    $(".btn-success").removeClass('btn-danger');
    $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div >
  <button class="btn btn-success">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Button 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Button 3</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```