# Switch color of button on click (and revert color of other buttons without deselecting all the buttons on the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have many buttons divided into different panels and I would like to change the color of a button when I click it in jquery. I can not use the solution present in this discussion: [Changing the Color of button on Click in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144982/changing-the-color-of-button-on-click-in-bootstrap)

```
$("button").click(function({$("button").removeClass("active");$(this).addClass("active");});
```

because I must have a button selected for each panel, and with this solution when I click on the button it also deselects me those of the other panels.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Refer to [MCVE]

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with `$("button").removeClass("active")`. As @Alex Wu explains, this effects all buttons, not just the one you click.

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing

```
$("button").click(function({
  // this removes the "active" class from all buttons
  $("button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

`$("button")` selects all of the buttons.

Suggestions:

This will "select" each button that is clicked

```
$("button").click(function({
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

If you want a click to "select" the button and then another click to "de-select" the button

```
$("button").click(function({
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```