# How to change color of button in active state using inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to change the background color and/or border color of a button when it is in active state (i.e. Clicked) using inline css?

```html
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-top: 12px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin-right:20px">
```

Something like this but for when the button is clicked?

Comment: no...it's not possible...you can provide inline css only for the default state...any changes required for a different must be in a stylesheet or must be inside a style tag

Comment: How can it be done inside a style tag?

Comment: use the :active selector

Comment: This should be a possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712267/how-to-change-the-button-color-when-it-is-active-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that css `:active` is just a *css pseudo-class* and not a `Dom property or attribute` you can't have an inline equivalent for that.

But, if in your case, the click event could be a valid alternative, you can do something like that...

```html
<script>
  function toggleBg(element, color) {
    if(!color) {
      color = element.dataset.normalColor;
    } else {
      element.dataset.normalColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    }

    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
</script>

<button onmousedown="toggleBg(this,'red')" onmouseup="toggleBg(this)">RED ON PRESS</button>
```

Just a note, inline-styling or inline-javascript isn't a good practice, if you can, use css:

```html
<style>
  button:active { background: red; }
</style>

<button>RED WHEN ACTIVE</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why is inline-styling not a god practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the background color and/or border color of a button when it is in active state (i.e. Clicked) using inline css, You can use `:active` in calss to change baground color or border color

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any reason why we can't access btn:active inline?

Comment: I think we can't use btn:active is the event which is going to happen after button is clicked and that and only by css or js by triggering it and etc. In short that class will be not abel to render properly by inline so we can't use it.